# WMI Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory class doesn't exist

Tags: windows, windows-7, wmi, windows-registry

The Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory WMI class (and many others) don't seem to exist.

From a scripting perspective I asked this question when I couldn't get Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory to return anything:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467013/err-80041017-when-querying-wmi-on-identical-computers-win32-perfformatteddata

After hours and hours of digging I am pretty sure this is more of an IT question surrounding a greater WMI issue.

One of my first stops was to use the WMI Diagnosis Utility:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684

I have these errors in the log file that WMIDiag.vbs produces:

```
..239 14:07:07 (1) !! ERROR: Unable to access or find file '%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\WBEM\AACLIENT.MOF' listed in 'Autorecover MOFs'.



..356 14:07:07 (1) !! ERROR: Unable to access or find file '%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\WBEM\EN-US\AACLIENT.MFL' listed in 'Autorecover MOFs'.

..415 14:07:07 (1) !! ERROR: Unable to access or find file '%WINDIR%\SYSTEM32\WBEM\FR-FR\AACLIENT.MFL' listed in 'Autorecover MOFs'.
Windows 7 workstation
Latest updates (as-of 1/29/2018)

..650 14:07:11 (1) !! ERROR: (ReadRegistry) : 0x80070002 - Invalid root in registry key "HKCR\CLSID\{FD209E2E-813B-41C0-8646-4C3E9C917511}\InProcServer32\".
..651 14:07:11 (1) !! ERROR: (CheckWMIDCOMComponentRegistrations) : 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM\IPMIPRV.DLL' is not registered correctly, missing '\CLSID\{FD209E2E-813B-41C0-8646-4C3E9C917511}\InProcServer32'.

..735 14:07:11 (1) !! ERROR: (ReadRegistry) : 0x80070002 - Invalid root in registry key "HKCR\CLSID\{9042E1B1-8FD4-4008-89FE-4040CC74575A}\InProcServer32\".
..736 14:07:11 (1) !! ERROR: (CheckWMIDCOMComponentRegistrations) : 'C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM\SERVERCOMPPROV.DLL' is not registered correctly, missing '\CLSID\{9042E1B1-8FD4-4008-89FE-4040CC74575A}\InProcServer32'.

23725 14:14:41 (1) !! ERROR: No Win32_LogicalDisk information available.

23745 14:14:41 (1) !! ERROR: No Win32_LogicalDisk information available.

28569 14:15:48 (1) !! ERROR: WMI GET operation errors reported: ........................................................................... 118 ERROR(S)!
28570 14:15:48 (0) ** - Root/CIMV2, Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_HTTPServiceRequestQueues, 0x0 - .
28571 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
28572 14:15:48 (0) ** - Root/CIMV2, Win32_PerfRawData_Counters_HTTPServiceRequestQueues, 0x0 - .
28573 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
28574 14:15:48 (0) ** - Root/CIMV2, Win32_PerfFormattedData_Counters_HTTPServiceUrlGroups, 0x0 - .
28575 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
...etc...
28693 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
28694 14:15:48 (0) ** - Root/CIMV2, Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory, 0x0 - .
28695 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
28696 14:15:48 (0) ** - Root/CIMV2, Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory, 0x0 - .
28697 14:15:48 (0) **   MOF Registration: 'WMI information not available (This could be the case for an external application or a third party WMI provider)'
```

I have tried all sorts of fixes and have found none that work. Making registry changes really isn't my skill set, but that is where I am headed next...I guess.

Please let me know what else you need. I am working on this right now. So whatever else I find I will add to this question. Thanks!

EDIT1: Windows 7 Pro, with all the latest updates. 64bit.

EDIT2: Is there any chance this could be caused by extremely low free RAM?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I can't answer my own question, but this solved it:     `cd %windir%\system32\
    lodctr /R
    cd %windir%\sysWOW64\
    lodctr /R`  See this link for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467013/err-80041017-when-querying-wmi-on-identical-computers-win32-perfformatteddata/48631020#48631020